# jquery content editable indent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking for a few hours now, and still can't work it out.

So I am working on a text editor and I want it so when they press the '**tab**' key it indents the text, that either I have selected or the text in front of my cursor text selector. I have been looking in to design mode and I've tried to make one element designMode but you can't unless I was doing it wrong. This is my code, that starts up my simple editor

```
 $(".code").click(function () {
   $(".code").attr('contenteditable', 'true');
   document.getElementById("code").designMode = "on";
 });
```

and then the '**tab key code**'

```
$(".code")
  .keydown(function (e) {      
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();

  }
});
```

**Question:** How do you indent in contenteditable for example in a texteditor you can indent nothing or text. (I dont have any problems with my key events not firing)

This is not a textarea or input box, its just a contenteditable div

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the problem? Is your keydown not firing? not preventing the default? not inserting the tab? Also you shouldn't use ||window.event in jQuery events; it handles all that automatically and the event object you get isn't a standard event object.

Comment: it is firing fine, but i just want to indent something, but i have no idea on how to indent something in contenteditable

Comment: OK. I can't help you there, but you should update your question to emphasise that so that you can get the attention of someone who can. You're asking how to find the selected text and style it with an indent, rather than how to detect & block the tab key, which is how your question currently reads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i figured it out, code bellow

```
$(".code").keydown(function(e)
           {
              e = e || window.event;
              var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
              if (keyCode == 9)
              {
                e.preventDefault();
                  document.execCommand('styleWithCSS',true,null);
                  document.execCommand('indent',true,null);
              }
           });
```

Comment: I found this [link](http://tifftiff.de/contenteditable/compliance_test.html) for `contenteditable` with `execCommand()` which also includes a list of commands and compatibility for most modern browsers in a table. It is quite useful for making decisions about interactive content designs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that $(".code") is a textarea, and event happens when it is focused and on keydown.

```
$(function(){
    var c = $(".code");
    c.keydown(function (e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if(keyCode === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0,$(this).get(0).selectionStart) + "\t" + $(this).val().substring($(this).get(0).selectionEnd));
      }
    });
});
```

example on:

http://jsfiddle.net/hXxU9/

Comment: well, that would work if it was a textarea, but as the title says that its "contentEditable" div